Why such a token is considered to have a weak entropy?
I am using the following code in my code to send a password reset token to a user.
$token = md5($user_id . time());

Why this is considered as a bad approach being cited as it has a weak entropy? The above code would generate a scary-looking 32 bit token that an attacker cannot decipher at all.
Suppose md5 reverse engineering is not possible (Although it is).
My question is why this is a bad approach? How do I say it has a weak entropy? Is there a way I can calculate its entropy?

Not necessarily off topic here, but the folks over at [security.se] might give you a better answer

Your question will attract opinionated answers making your question off-topic.  "why this is a wrong approach?" Unsure why you think this is a bad approach to send out a token to reset a password to start with — Furthermore you are asking multiple questions at once. A question should focus on one programming-related problem at the time

@DarkBee the underlying question is same, as why it is a bad appraoch.. anyways thanks for the headup

Just because the value “looks scary” doesn’t mean it’s actually unguessable or “secure”.

"The above code would generate a scary-looking 32 bit token that an attacker cannot decipher at all" - even if an attacker could "decipher" anything from that token, what would be the point in getting more details? And how is this problem related to [tag:md5sum]?


How do I say it has a weak entropy?

Your function is deterministic: it produces same result for a given user id at a given time. So if both variables are known the entropy would be zero.

My question is why this is a bad approach?

So if I know a particular user id e.g. 123456 then all I need to do is:

Initiate a password reset request and note down timestamp of the request e.g. 1726476087
Brute force the password reset page with hashes generated for that user id and timestamp ± 5 seconds (to compensate for difference in two clocks):

$user_id = 123456;
$request_time = 1726476087;
for ($time = $request_time - 5; $time <= $request_time + 5; $time++) {
    $token = md5($user_id . $time);
    send_request("reset.php?token=" . $token);
}

The brute force approach could be also used for arbitrary user ids with some improvements e.g. calculate the exact different between the clocks and estimate the number of users in the system before hand.

I understand that but not all attackers has access to the source code. My question is how this is linked with entropy? and how we can say this is low entropy?

In other words: there’s zero randomness here, it’s all very deterministic and guessable. Hence virtually no entropy.

@deceze can I augment my no entropy logic through any formula or online tool, paper etc?

@Johnny Not sure what you mean by “augment the logic”. You’ll want to use an actual random number generator to generate an unpredictable, random value.

@deceze I mean if it is written somewhere that md5 produces low entropy or any tool like md5sum that would return entropy , so that I can say it has zero entropy.

@Johnny It’s not about MD5. The return value of an MD5 hash solely depends on its input. The problem is that your input has zero randomness. Whether you MD5 hash it or not is irrelevant.

MD5, or any other hash function, will not increase the enthropy at all. If there is n-bits of enthropy going in the output will still have n-bits of enthropy

Is there any way I can calcualte teh entropy of two strings, so for example the first string is 25, 85,100,120, and I can calcualte teh entropy?

@Johnny It’s about how many values your variable can potentially have, and the more equal the chances of each value are, the better the entropy/equal distribution among those potential values, hence the lower the guessability. In your case, for any password reset request at a given time, the token is guessable to be one of ~20 possible values. That’s how you need to think about this. How equal those 20 values are distributed is irrelevant, because there are so few to begin with that it makes no difference.

The normal way to create such a token is to use something like base64_encode(random_bytes(32)) and store that in your database for the user that asked a password reset. As you can see this is quite random, and has a high entropy: It could have any value.
